# How to add the median and IQR to a scatter plot in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have generated a scatter plot using the following code:

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Load the data from Excel
data <- read_excel("cfu calculator.xlsx")

# Calculate the median and IQR for each group on a specific day
median_value <- data %>%
  group_by(DAY, Group) %>%
  summarize(median = median(CFU))

iqr_value <- data %>%
  group_by(DAY, Group) %>%
  summarize(q1 = quantile(CFU, probs = 0.25),
            q3 = quantile(CFU, probs = 0.75),
            iqr = IQR(CFU))

ggplot(data, aes(DAY, CFU, color = Group)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("DAY") +
  ylab("CFU") +
  ggtitle("CFU of Infected vs Uninfected Over Time") +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Group", labels = c("Infected", "Uninfected"))
```

I like that each sample is visible, but I want to replace the individual data points with a line representing the median, and IQR. I would also like to remove the default grey background that comes with ggplot if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should provide parts of your data. You can do this with `dput`.

Here is an example using the mtcars dataset. What you have to do is to replace the values like this for your dataset:

```
#dataset = mtcars
#DAY = cyl
#Group = am
#CFU = mpg
```

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

summary_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am) %>%
  summarise(median = median(mpg),
            q1 = quantile(mpg, probs = 0.25),
            q3 = quantile(mpg, probs = 0.75), .groups = "drop"
  ) 
ggplot(summary_mtcars, aes(cyl, median, color = factor(am))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_linerange(data = summary_mtcars, aes(cyl, ymin = q1, ymax = q3),
                 color = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = quantile(mtcars$mpg, 0.25), linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = quantile(mtcars$mpg, 0.75), linetype = "dotted") +
    xlab("DAY") +
    ylab("CFU") +
    ggtitle("CFU of Infected vs Uninfected Over Time") +
    scale_color_discrete(name = "Group", labels = c("Infected", "Uninfected"))
```

[image]